# ag-grid: Using Grid Event CellClicked for specific column - cannot access "this"

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have a column in grid which when clicked I am trying to access some method of class but the `this` context has changed and not available. 
Ex -

```
export class PreTflGridComponent implements OnInit {  

  columnDefs = [
    {onCellClicked: this.editCellClicked}
  ];

  constructor() { }   

  method(): void {
      console.log('working');
  }

  editCellClicked(params) {
    this.method();
  }  

}
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.method is not a function
```

How can I access the methods/properties once the `this` context has changed.

Refer below for the exact issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwgcc2, if you will click the column make and open up console then it would show the error I am facking.

Comment: Could you recreate your issue on StackBlitz?

Comment: added on Stackblitz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` seems to be giving you the actual row. What you need to do is tell your `makeCellClicked` method what `this` actually is by binding `this` to it like:

`onCellClicked: this.makeCellClicked.bind(this)`.

Please also see your [updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2ahfb) StackBlitz.

Comment: yes, this works but now the click event is on all cells. I have a big table and I want it only on one of the columns. Also for other/future uses why it's not binding? or how can I access the original `this`

Comment: thx, mine js is so bad :( this is plain old js concept. You can mention the other answer too as an alternative if you wish.

Comment: No need as I think it's irrelevant in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cellRenderer property with simple logic. More convenient way for complex logic renderer you should use cellRendererFramework: YourCustomRendererAngularComponent.

```
columnDefs = [
{
  headerName: 'Col Name',
  cellRendererFramwork: MyAngularRendererComponent, // RendererComponent suffix it is naming convention
  cellRendererParams: {
    onClick: (params) => this.click(params);  
  }
},
...
]
```

MyAngularRendererComponent should implements AgRendererComponent.

Also in angular module where you use MyAngualrRendererComponent don`t forget put this code:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   AgGridModule.withCompoennts([
      MyAngualrRendererComponent 
   ])
 ]
})
```

The above code is just a small part, check out full example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I added problem on stackblitz, your answer doesn't seem to address the problem, pls del or modify